# Not able to split value of a column in dataframe on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input data frame which looks like

```
   0      1
0  0  10,30
1  1  10,40
2  2  20,50
```

Now I am trying to split the second column and store the value in to a new column. Here if the value in column A is divisible by 2 then get the first value from column B else second value like below

```
   A      B   C
0  0  10,30  10
1  1  10,40  10
2  2  20,50  50
```

My Code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([(0, '10,30'), (1, '10,40'), (2, '20,50')])

df['n'] = np.where(df[0] % 2 == 0, df[0], 0 )
df[2] = (df[1]).str.split(',').str[df['n'].fillna(0)

print(df)
```

Its throwing an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Is first value `10` ? not `30`?

Comment: @jezrael My bad first value is `30`

Comment: Hmm, then seems need select if condition is `True` second splitted value, if False first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)ed column to `DataFrame` and cast boolean mask to int for select first column by `0` and second column by `1`:

```
df[2] = df[1].str.split(',', expand=True).lookup(df.index, (df[0] % 2 == 0).astype(int))
print (df)
   0      1   2
0  0  10,30  30
1  1  10,40  10
2  2  20,50  50

print (df[0] % 2 == 0)
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool

#select second, first, second column
print ((df[0] % 2 == 0).astype(int))
0    1
1    0
2    1
Name: 0, dtype: int32
```

Similar solution with changed condition:

```
df[2] = df[1].str.split(',', expand=True).lookup(df.index, (df[0] % 2 != 0).astype(int))
print (df)
   0      1   2
0  0  10,30  10
1  1  10,40  40
2  2  20,50  20
```

```
print (df[0] % 2 != 0)
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool

#select first, second, first column
print ((df[0] % 2 != 0).astype(int))
0    0
1    1
2    0
Name: 0, dtype: int32

print (df[1].str.split(',', expand=True))
    0   1
0  10  30 <-first 10
1  10  40 <-second 40
2  20  50 <-first 20
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also achieve it with the method `apply`.

First let's put the column 1 splited together with the target index into a new dataframe `df1`

```
df1 = pd.concat({i:df[1].str.split(',').str.get(i) for i in range(2)}, axis=1)
df1['ind'] = df[0] % 2
df1

    0   1   ind
0   10  30  0
1   10  40  1
2   20  50  0
```

Next you can put the new values into the column 2 with

```
df[2] = df1.apply(lambda p: p.loc[p["ind"]], axis=1)
df[2]

0    10
1    40
2    20
dtype: object
```

If you don't want to create a new data frame, you can also do the following to get the same result

```
df[2] = df1.apply(lambda p: p.loc[1].split(",")[p.loc[0] % 2], axis=1)
```